# Align math to the left

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

I need to align math to the left. I tried to add `[fleqn]` option to the `\documentclass` command - it works but now all equations in the document are aligned to the left which isn't what I want.

My LaTeX code looks like this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Classic math which I don't want align to the left

\[
    2x + 5
\]

Multiline math which must be left-aligned   

\begin{gather*}
    x^2 + 3 \\
    2x - 5
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

`gather*` environment is used only for example. Is there any environment instead of `gather*` which is suitable for my needs? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

That's a rather strange requirement, perhaps easiest is if you use `$$` instead of `\[`. `$$` is officially not supported syntax, the main problem being that it does *not*+ work with `fleqn` which seems to be exactly what you want here.

Note never leave a blank line above a display math, whether `$$`, `\[` or `\begin{align}`

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Classic math which I don't want align to the left
$$
    2x + 5
$$

Multiline math which must be left-aligned   
\begin{gather*}
    x^2 + 3 \\
    2x - 5 \\
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do that nesting `gathered` in a`flalign(*)` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

Classic math which I don't want align to the left

\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
    x^2 + 3 \\
    2x - 5 = z
    \end{gathered}
\end{equation}

Multiline math which must be left-aligned
\begin{flalign}
\hskip\parindent & \begin{gathered}
    x^2 + 3 \\
    2x - 5 = z
    \end{gathered} &
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]